# IIS SMTP Relay to gmail fails occasionally

Tags: iis, smtp, windows-server-2016, iis-6

I'm using IIS SMTP relay to gmail to send outbound emails. I create this email text file with SSIS script task and place the file in the Pickup directory. This script runs every 15 minutes. It works most of the time, but sporadically it fails with the following error message. Using Windows Server 2016, so maybe there's a better way to manage SMTP relay?

> Unable to deliver this message because the follow error was encountered: "Error is processing file in pickup directory.". The specific error code was 0xC00402CE.

I don't believe it has anything to do with the email format (receivers or sender) because the same email will successfully send later without generating the error. However, sometimes it gets "stuck" for hours at a time which I need to resolve. Also, if I simply copy/paste the file in the Pickup directory, it sends every time.

Comment: File lock perhaps? Something (presumably the script task) not releasing its connection to the file occasionally so it's seen as being open/in use still? Can you get the file saved elsewhere initially, and then copy/move it to the pickup directory? Either that may resolve the issue, or if the copy operation has the same issue you might at least get a usful error from SSIS when it fails to complete that step.

Comment: @KeithLangmead That's exactly what I'm doing...I create the file in a backup directory and then copy to the Pickup directory. That's why I'm able to copy/paste the file so easily. Unfortunately though there are no detailed error messages.